# How did Dropbox implement these two features (changing icons & sending only difference in file changes.)

Tags: windows, synchronization, diff, dropbox

How did DropBox implement these two features (a high-level answer is fine):

1. Get the icon of a file to change once it's synchronised on Windows? (I am guessing similar answers would apply to the other OSs)
2. Send only the changes done to a file and not the whole file?

For 2, I am guessing that it worked by using something similar to diff on the client side, and sending the output...

Comment: TortoiseSVN does this, too, and it's code is open-source. You can find out for yourself.

Comment: TortoiseSVN **doesn't** do diffing, it relies on SVN to do the diffing.

Answer (score 2):

As for the first question, it's done using an [icon overlay handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761265%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). There's an example in [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/overlayicon.aspx), and you can also take a look at the great [TortoiseSVN source](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/trunk/src/TortoiseShell/IconOverlay.cpp), which implements such a handler.

Comment: Thanks looking at example project always helps.

Answer (score 0):

Only sending modifications to a file is accomplished with something called a [Rolling Checksum / Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash), an example of a program that can remotely diff a file and only send the differences is [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).